# VSCODE not properly color coding my script code -- all white characters?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vue-cli-3, prettier

I am working with VSCODE and have been writing Vue applications with no issues. However, all of a sudden, it seems VSCODE is not properly color coding my JavaScript code. All the JS code within the `<script>` section is of a white font. I don't see any lint errors under the PROBLEMS tab. Here is what it looks like:

Anyone know how to fix this? All my other `.vue` files are fine....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be the "table caption" slot  item within the `<template>` element was not being properly formatted. I deleted that line and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file extension is correct for the type of content – VSCode uses the file extension to determine formatting.

Comment: I am using a .vue file . It was working before. no longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If it is because you do not want the white letters to be seen then install the following extension in VS code:

- Name: vue
- Id: jcbuisson.vue
- Description: Syntax Highlight for Vue.js
- Version: 0.1.5
- Publisher: jcbuisson VS Marketplace
- Link:       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jcbuisson.vue

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out that no extension was recognizing the following line

```
<td v-if="typeof value != 'object'">{{value}}</td>
```

I replaced it with a function in methods as:

```
    type(value){
       return typeof value;
    }
```

And then the line in template becomes:

```
<td v-if="type(value) != 'object'">{{value}}</td>
```